# Delphi ADO rounds decimal values from SQL Server

Tags: delphi, decimal, ado

I have a Table (MS SQL Server) with fields of data type decimal(18,8).
In my application I enter value 0.000089 and save it.
I check with SQL Server Management Studio the table and the value is OK (0.00008000).
But when I use TADOQuery to read the value, it's return 0.0001 (always rounded to 4 decimals position - 0.123456789 -> 0.1235). I try TADOTable with TDataSource and TDBTable, also ADOExplorer tool and result was the same.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Please read [accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disable the [`EnableBCD`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOQuery_EnableBCD.html) property in your `TADOQuery` component

when `EnableBCD` is true, it can support to 4 decimal places.
when `EnableBCD` is false , the field is mapped to `TFloatField`.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! Right now I found that field is determined as BCD and will start to search why.

Comment: @MadDog, You can thank him by upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: Oops, Sorry. I did it